# Page has to be refreshed in order to get data from the api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a working auth. flow. There is just one strange bug. When I log in with a first user I first have to refresh the page in order to get data in my view. When I log out with this user and a next user logs in I still have the data of user1 in my view. If I log out again with user2 and log in with user3 I have the data of user2 in my view. So it seems like its always one behind. I tried to fix it with with destroying the subscription, but that didn't solve the problem. Also when I think that bug begins when I have to refresh my page in order to get my first users data, to destroy the subscription cannot be the errors solution.

This is my code:

auth.service: Where I post the users credentials, give back a token, and store it and the user_id in order to get the authenticated users data in the view.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';


export const TOKEN_KEY = 'access_token';
export const USERNAME_KEY = 'username_key';
export const USER_ID = 'user_id';
...
user = null;
refreshToken = null;
authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private helper: JwtHelperService) {
      this.checkToken();
   }

   checkToken() {
       this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
           if (access) {
               this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(access);
               this.authenticationState.next(true);
           }
       });
   }

   apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
        tap(res => {
            this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, res['access']);
            this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, username);
            this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.user['user_id']);
            this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']);
            console.log('my user: ', this.user);
            this.authenticationState.next(true);
        }));
}

apilogout() {
    this.storage.remove(USER_ID);
    this.storage.remove(USERNAME_KEY);
    this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY).then(() => {
    this.authenticationState.next(false);
   });
}
```

page.ts: here I get the data that I display in my view. (user service just retrieves a single user. In the end I destroy the subscription)

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { USER_ID } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { SubscriptionLike } from 'rxjs';

  information = null;
  id: number;
  key: string;
  subscription: SubscriptionLike;

  constructor(private storage: Storage,  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private userService: UserService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // How to get just the authenticated api?
      if (this.authService.authenticationState) {
      console.log(this.storage);
      this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => {
        this.id = val;
        this.subscription = this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
          this.information = result;
          console.log(this.information);
        });
      });
    }

  }

ngOnDestroy() {
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
this.information = null;
}
```

login.ts (handles my routing to the main page)

```
 // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
...

apiSubmit() {
  console.log('Hello World');
  this.submitted = true;

  // if form is invalid => stop
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.loadingEl.present();
  this.authService.apilogin(
  this.f.username,
  this.f.password)
      .pipe(tap(x => this.loadingEl.dismiss()),
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('0');
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('1');
          this.loadingEl.dismiss();
          this.error = error;
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
}
```

authGuard

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private authService: AuthService
  ) { }


  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `if (this.authService.authenticationState) {` you should actually subscribe to this observable. Also we need to remember that setting or getting or removing from ionic `Storage` is actually asynchronous. We need to wait that the action has been performed before doing anything else. Also I suggest to instead of calling `next` on your observable, just call `checkToken()` that can do the check and then call `next` on the BehaviorSubject.

This should work:

Service:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, of, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

private authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
public authenticationState$ = this.authenticationState.asObservable();

checkToken() {
  this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
    if (access) {
      this.authenticationState.next(true);
    } else {
      this.authenticationState.next(false);
    }
  });
}

apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}`, { username, password }).pipe(
    // switch to inner observable
    switchMap((data: any) => {
      // run all in paralell
      return forkJoin(
        this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, 'access'),
        this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, 'username'),
        this.storage.set(USER_ID, 'id'),
      )
    }),
    // now we know for sure storage values have been set,
    // therefore call checkToken()
    tap(() => this.checkToken()),
  )
}

// seems you are not currently subscribing to this function in the
// component, so I guess you can subscribe here, but I'd subscribe in comp
apilogout() {
  forkJoin(
    this.storage.remove(USER_ID),
    this.storage.remove(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY),
    this.storage.remove(USERNAME_KEY),
    this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY)
  ).subscribe(() => this.checkToken())
}
```

Then the component would subscribe to your BehaviorSubject and do whatever you need to do:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sub = this.authService.authenticationState$.pipe(
    switchMap((data) => {
      return data ? this.storage.get(USER_ID) : of(null)
    }),
    switchMap((id: any) => {
      this.id = id;
      return id ? this.userService.getUserDetails(id) : of(null)
    })
  ).subscribe(val => {
    // do stuff!
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

PS. DON'T use `any`, type your data to models :)

Comment: I have implemented your solution. But when I want to login my page doesn't navigate into the app like it used to do. Somehow my subscribe doesn't of into the `data =>` path anymore but end in `error =>` I added the part `login.ts`in my question. Do I have to add here also something. I mean there were some heavy restructures made now

Comment: I actually don't get an error. I get back my user data, but I end in => error because it  consol logs 1 so I just don't navigate to my main page:( I have still added my authGuard maybe its because of that. But that then everything Im using in this context here

Comment: try removing the guard just for testing, so you know if it's causing the issue.

Comment: Its not causing the issue. I just removed the canActivate in the routing-module, nothing changed

Comment: how does your apilogin function look like now? Completely like mine? I don't understand how it could error if an error doesn't happen... if it goes to the error block `console.log(error)` should produce something.

Comment: `TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.   at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:28)
    at from (from.js:10)
    at _loop_1 (forkJoin.js:40)
    at Observable._subscribe (forkJoin.js:65)
    at ` Yes the function looks like yours. This is the beginning of the error.

Comment: Sounds like somewhere an object is returned, but such thing is not in the apilogin function. You sure you passed `of(data)` and not `data` inside the forkJoin?

Comment: So does `this.http.post<any>(${this.url}, { username, password })` return anything? I mean if you don't use it inside your component you can remove it altogether. I updated my answer.

Comment: But `this.http.post<any>(${this.url}, { username, password })`posts my data to the server? Without that how should I post my credentials to the api